# finding neighboring polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a multi-polygon consisting of the second administrative units of the DRC, Uganda, and Burundi, each identified by a field id (fid).I need to find the neighboring polygons for each fid. There are some online sources on how to do this, e.g., https://spatialthoughts.com/2019/05/23/neighbor-polygons-aggregate-qgis/
I tried the following approach using the field calculator :

```
aggregate(
layer:= 'MAP',
aggregate:='concatenate',
expression:=to_string("fid"),
concatenator:=', ',
filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent))
)
```

In the beginning, this approach looks promising and the preview of the out seems right (23,42,43). However, when I perform the analysis the newly created variable has the value  `NULL`  in every row. I read that this is sometimes caused by the polygons not touching each other and can be solved by creating a buffered version of my initial layer. This unfortunately did not solve the problem.

Comment: Is the datatype of your output field set to `Text`? Perhaps the expression works but it is trying to insert strings into a number field.

Comment: That solved it!